# Why do I repeatingly get an error popup for crash reports in /var/crash?

Tags: gnome, crash, 19.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my main machine and received an error popup shortly after each login or startup. It only told me that an error occurs with two buttons *cancel* and *report*. No way to get more detailed information what exactly went wrong.

So I looked in the syslog and found this entrys:

```
Jun 22 21:02:53 my-pc gnome-shell[5246]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to update overlay icon 
Jun 22 21:02:53 my-pc gnome-shell[5246]: message repeated 2 times: [[AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to update overlay icon]
```

Some research found this in a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/+bug/1825623) where [one comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/+bug/1825623/comments/9) indicate that the error popup was caused by crash reports in `/var/crash`. It seems the user did an OS upgrade. I had a fresh install but also some crash reports in those folder, may related to some tests (e.g. Steam Proton where GTA5 crashed).

After deleting those crash reports and rebooting the system, no error popups occur any more. But on the previous popups, I always pressed *report* because I want Ubuntu to be able to fix the issue.

#### So why those popup occurs repeatingly on every boot, altough I let them send the error reports?

I'd expect that the crash-data got deleted after reporting. Or at least marked as deleted, so that I didn't get promted any time. It seems that Ubuntu promted me multiple time for the same crash. Because the last crash report in `/var/crash` was from yesterday. Today I rebootet/logged out multiple times for testing purpose and got this popup each time.